# Non-default constructed boost::proto terminal

Tags: c++, boost, boost-proto

I'm trying to define a very limited parser combinator library using boost::proto and was wondering if it's by any means possible to define a non-default constructed proto terminal.

I have a structure like this:

```
struct symbol
{
   symbol(const string &str): str_(str) {}
   bool operator()(const string &str) const {
      return (str == str_);
   }

   string str_;
};
```

that I'd like to use as a boost proto terminal in proto expressions. I was able to get it to work with the help of `BOOST_PROTO_DEFINE_OPERATORS`, but I find it somewhat inconvenient to frequently have to wrap it in a `proto::lit()` inside proto expressions:

```
match(symbol("abc") >> (proto::lit(symbol("xyz")) | symbol("klm")))
```

I was wondering if I could create a proto terminal like this:

```
proto::terminal<symbol>::type sym;
```

that would somehow be able to take a string argument and pass it to the constructor of symbol.

**Note:** I know about Spirit, but my compiler doesn't quite support it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make the name `sym` a function that returns a terminal:

```
proto::terminal<symbol>::type sym(std::string const& s)
{ return { symbol(s) }; }
```

much like `lit` is a function template that turns its parameter into a terminal.